# How do I get the Screw modifier to generate a face at the end?

Tags: modifiers, screw-modifier

[[Example (old link)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gxse.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gxse.jpg)[image: Image with desired result on the left]
^ Desired result on the left

Here the end faces are missing. Is it possible to get them there or to generate them at every step?

Comment: Can you share an example simplified blend to look at? We can then get a better idea of what you are up against.

Comment: will do tomorrow. sorry, am about to sleep now

Comment: @CraigDJones I added an image that should illustrate my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps add a solidify modifier and get it that way?[image]

Comment: No, I mean the face you'd get if you pressed F on the end of the screw

Comment: Sorry, can't see the intended effect from the original post image.

Comment: So the original mesh is just one face. Now if I apply the screw modifier, the edges around the face get rotated and copied, but the face itself vanishes.

Comment: I have added a new image

Comment: I tried but I think this warrants a proposal on rightclickselect.com

Answer (score 1):

Hi was looking at your image. Drew similar object and found that I had to enter the parameters and then apply the *Screw Modifier*, select the object, enter *Edit Mode*
[image]

Select two edges and type <kbd>F</kbd> for fill.

Not sure if it will work for you. Image on left has modifier applied and face added. Blender 2.8 on Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: I know, I was asking if it's possible to do it *in* the modifier. If I apply the modifier and then work on it, I lost the benefit of the modifier.